# Accumulation Points Proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I got the following sequence ${a}_n = (-1)^n + \frac{1}{n}$

I want to show that for an optional $x \epsilon \mathbb{R}\setminus \left \{ 1,-1 \right \}$ that there is no subsequence $({a}_n)_n \epsilon \mathbb{N}$ that converges to x.

It is pretty obvious that ${a}_n$ has two accumulation points.
The first for the subsequence

$({a}_k)$ and $k=2n $ that converges to $1$

and $({a}_l)$ and $l=2n+1  $ that converges to $-1$

It's pretty obvious that those are the only accumulation points but I have difficulties to proof it.

How can I show that $1$ and $-1$ are the only accumulation points?

First I tried something like every indexset is equal, inequal or mixed.
But an indexset that has inequal numbers for the first 20 numbers and the rest is equal is also mixed but still converges. I always got the felling to miss something.

Now I try a distinction of cases and maybe a contradiction proof.
I differentiate the cases $x<-1 , x>1 , -1 < x < 1$
I want to show that you cannot find a accumulation point in this range set ($x \epsilon \mathbb{R}\setminus \left \{ 1,-1 \right \}$)

The first two cases are easy. The limit of ${a}_n$ cant be smaller than $-1$ because $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to zero and $(-1)^n$ cant be smaller than $-1$.

The same goes for the second case but I cant get the third case done. How can I show that $-1 < x < 1$ is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0<x<1$ let $\delta=\min(x,1-x).$ Then use $\varepsilon=\delta/2,$ so if some subsequence converged to $x$ there would be a large $N$ for which $n \ge N$ implies $|a_n-x|<\varepsilon.$ But as $n$ increases this cannot be, given how $\varepsilon$ is defined, will leave rest of details to check.

Note: The remaining case is really $-1<x<1$ and my $\delta$ above should be reset to $\delta=\min(x-(-1),1-x).$ The rest is the same.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. My only problem is $\delta = min(x,1-x)$
When $x = -0.7$ ; $ min(x,1-x) = -0.7$ so $\varepsilon = \frac{-0.7}{2}$
but $\left | {a}_n -x \right |$ is for an inequal and very high $n$ $ =0.3$
And $0.3 < \frac{0.7}{2}$ 

I thought $ \varepsilon > 0 $ and if I take the absolute value it doesnt work in my example. Where is my fault?

Comment: Oops I somehow thought $0<x<1$ was the remaining case. So if you reset my $\delta$ to $\delta=\min(x-(-1),1-x))$ where $-1<x<1$ the rest works I think.

Comment: @Erdbeer0815 Forgot to include your user name in the last comment. I included the redefined $\delta$ in the answer. For the value $x=-0.7$ it gives $\delta=0.3,$ so $\varepsilon = 0.15.$ Then around $x$ the interval is $(-0.85,-0.55)$ and for large $n$ the subsequence cannot be in there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to prove that all converging subsequences converge to either $1$ or $-1$.

Let us consider $s_n = a_{f(n)}$ a converging subsequence of $a_n$

Let us assume that $f$ takes an infinite number of odd values and an infinite number of even values. Then, $s_n$ and subsequences that converge to two different limits, and does not converge. Which contradicts our hypothesis.

Hence, $f$ has a either a finite number of odd values or a finite number of even values.

I let you finish.

Rq : always think about the contraposite.